# Cant select Qt kit

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I've recently installed Qt, and I am trying to make a project, but I need to select a kit to continue making the project, however, the two kits that are shown are greyed out and I don't know how to select them.

Its a QtWidgets project saved in documents

Build System is qmake

Class Name is MainWindow

Base Class is QMainWindow

Header File is mainwindow.h

Source File is mainwindow.cpp

Form File is mainwindow.ui

What the screen looks like:

[image: What the screen looks like]

[image]

Do I need to install anything? Or have special configurations? Thanks

Comment: Do you have MSVC 2019 installed?

Comment: yes i have the x86 version and the x64 int the vcredist folder

Comment: Click the "options" link in your screenshot. What do you see? Do you have any warning icons in your list of Kits?

Comment: @JKSH yes, i edited the question to show this

Comment: @JaydenCollis You have yellow warning icons. Hover your mouse cursor over the icons and show us the warning message. Also post the contents of your **Qt Versions** tab.

Comment: Note: StackOverflow is more for questions about coding. Questions about installing the Qt framework are better suited for, say, the [Qt Forum](https://forum.qt.io/)

Comment: There is no error

Comment: @JKSH the error was no debugger

Comment: @JaydenCollis OK. Can you add details to your question about what type of project you tried to create?

Comment: @JKSH Edited. Is that what you were looking for

Comment: @JaydenCollis Yep, perfect. That looks fine to me... what **Qt Version** did you use in your kits? Also, you said _"yes i have the x86 version and the x64 int the vcredist folder"_ -- Do you have the MSVC 2019 **compiler**? (The redistributation version is not enough)

Comment: @JKSH  where would the msvc 2019 be stored?

Comment: Im going to try reinstalling qt

Comment: @JaydenCollis You must download MSVC2019 from Microsoft directly and install the **C++ compiler**: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ Then, you must install **Qt 5.15.0 for MSVC 2019 (32-bit)**

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for this is to open a blank file, save it as filename.ui, and fill it with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>ClassName</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="ClassName">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>553</width>
    <height>520</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Then I right click the file and select "open in QT Creator"